# Is tab completion in terminal on OSX directory-sensitive?

Tags: macos, terminal

Why does tab completion only work some of the time in OS X terminal? e.g. `cd docu`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

For example, when I'm at `/Users/` it works fine. But when I'm at `~/` it doesn't work at all.

Once inside `~/Documents/` it works again. What's the deal? I'm definitely typing enough to remove any ambiguity from the subfolders.

Comment: I've just tried in both and it works fine. Perhaps you're typing some UTF8 hidden characters, that are invisible but of which your shell (I assume bash) is aware ? Also beware that it's case sensitive (you mentioned `cd docu`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tab completion is case sensitive.

Your username is usually all lowercase, which is why `cd username` works in `/Users`, but not `cd docu` in `~` — the folder name is *Documents*, with an uppercase *D*.

If you want to change this behavior, add the following lines to your `~/.inputrc`.

```
$if Bash
  set completion-ignore-case On
$endif
```

If you do not have an `~/.inputrc` you can create one and add the above with this command:

```
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

Comment: when i create the inputrc i have no permissions to modify it. how can i give myself permissions

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of MacOS (10.15+) use `zsh` in the terminal so you will need to configure that instead.

Add these lines to `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
```

More info here:
https://superuser.com/a/1092328/222897