# How can I make zsh tab completion fix capitalization errors for directories and files?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, tab-completion

I switched to zsh completely on a previous arch install and I LOVED it mainly because arch is one of the distros that capitalizes your Documents, Downloads, Music and such directories in your ~ directory. Since I wasn't used to that and I use tab completion for almost everything in the terminal zsh was like heaven for me compared to bash.... I swear this feature used to be active automatically because I don't remember having to tweak anything to make it work that way. I probably figured it out on accident. xD But I would greatly like to have this feature restored on my new pc using zsh as my main shell, and if anyone knows how to do this I would really appreciate a reply. I tried activating every option in the completion configuration and that didn't seem to do the trick... so that brought me here.

PS: I used to be a lot more up to date with my Linux know-how, and my knowledge has grown stale... I'm trying to remedy that... (without the use of the shift key, as much as possible... haha)

Comment: Welcome to SU! To improve your style a comment: Your question is rather difficult to read, because there is a lot of unnecessary information. Please edit you question and try to concentrate on the relevant infos. Keep it short and simple `;)`.

Answer (score 93):

**TL;DR**:
This is possible if you put these lines in your `zsh` config file, usually `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
```

---

A little bit more information:

This is possible when using the  *zsh completion system* (started by `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`) and is controlled by a *zstyle*:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Za-z}'
```

This tells `zsh` that small letters will match small and capital letters. (i.e. capital letters match only capital letters.)

If you want that capital letters also match small letters use instead:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

If you want case-insensitive matching only if there are no case-sensitive matches add `''`, e.g.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}'
```

See also the description of `matcher-list`  in `man zshcompsys`.

Comment: @Aaron: Glad to hear. Please consider to accept my answer then as explained in the [SU tour](http://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: So where do I put `zstyle`?

Comment: @inherithandle: It's a normal shell (builtin) command, you can execute it on the command line. If you wan't that behavior permanent, put it into your `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: I have added the above setting to my `.zshrc` and sourced it, but it does not seem to work. I have also tried to use the command in command line to no avail. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: @jdhao: Maybe you haven't initialized the completion system, use some other 3rd party settings (d'oh-my-zsh), etc... so, this is too complex to debug in the comments. Try to construct a minimal(!) case of your config files and write a separate question; something like "Why have my zstyle settings no effect?"

Comment: @mpy Thanks for your kind reply. I have found that we need to add `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit` after the zstyle command to make the setting take effect. Maybe it is worthwhile to mention that in the answer for zsh novices like me...

Comment: @jdhao: Yes, good point. I added this to the introductory sentence.

Comment: Please rewrite the answer so one doesn't have to scan all the comments to figure out what one needs to do. Like:
(1) create a file (2) add "A" to the file (3) add "B" to the file
This is superuser, not Serverfault or Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @jitbit: I added a "summary" with a snippet for easy copy&paste. I hope this will help to get this working faster.

Comment: @mpy thank you sir!